# Replacing dash value from another dataframe on the basis of common user id Python Pandas Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to replace the dash(NA) value from another Data frame using a common ID column column

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please review [ask] and create a [mcve] showing your attempt at solving your own problem.

Comment: Please show us some of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Next time, please provide your datasets as text.

You can use:

```
df1.replace('-', pd.NA).combine_first(df2).loc[df1.index]
```

output:

```
     A   B
0  1.0  55
1  2.0  22
2  3.0  66
3  4.0  44
```